# Radio Buttons Pre-Selected in Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

So I've been working on this for hours. It seems like there is a glitch in the way that Bootstrap and jQuery interact with each other.

I can only get the radio buttons to visually be pre-selected if I wrap it in .input-group and use no attributes except for "checked" like so:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="radio" checked>
<label>Automatic</label>
<input type="radio">
<label>Custom</label>
</div>
```

This is driving me crazy, because I need to control how the form behaves in a non-standard way.

If I do the following, it breaks immediately:

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="one-group" value="automatic" checked>
<label>Automatic</label>
<input type="radio" name="one-group" value="custom">
<label>Custom</label>
</div>
```

I have been going into the source code, but I don't want to give the client a project that deviates from the standard too much.

Here's the problem:

It works functionally but not visibly. When I get it to work visibly (using spans in the label and such) it no longer works functionally. Short of writing a very complicated and specific plugin that redoes all the logic of "radio button", how do I fix this?

I am racking my brain for a solution, please help!

Comment: This question has **NOT** been answered, it is an issue with jQuery and Bootstrap, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since both radio buttons share the name, "one-group", and both are checked - it's not displaying it. Give the second radio button a different name. Radio buttons are mutually exclusive.

Comment: You probably meant "remove the checked attribute from one of the radio buttons" as the solution, didn't you? From the context she needs them to have the same name as they're related.